# Getting TypeError: urljoin is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

When I am trying to run the app I am getting TypeError: urljoin is not a function error the code is

const urljoin = require('url-join')

Comment: Can you provide more context? Do you have `url-join` the package installed in your `package.json`?

Comment: Looks like a typo. It should be urlJoin and jot urljoin as per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-join)

Comment: Yes, the package is installed in the package.json

Answer (score 1):

This is because you might be using an older version of url-join (the latest one is `5.0.0`).
For me, I was using an older version of `4.0.1`.
Follow the exact steps below to make it running:

```
const urljoin = require("url-join"); // import via require statement
return urljoin(arrayOfString);
```

Note: For the new version of [url-join](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-join) we import `urlJoin` but for older its all small characters i.e `urljoin`.

Hope this works!